# How to add unique constraint to an entity in JHipster?

Tags: jpa, constraints, jhipster

I have an entity called Author like the one below. I want to add a unique constraint on the field "name".

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "author")
public class Author implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column( name = "name")
    private String name;


    @Column(name = "birth_date")
    private LocalDate birthDate;
```

Answer (score 9):

The JHipster generator lacks of the option to generate unique fields for entities. To do it manually:

1. Generate entity
2. Add unique constraint in liquibase changelog xml (http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/add_unique_constraint.html)
3. Add unique=true parameter to **@Column** annotation.(https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Column.html)

I have only tested this in MySQL and PostgreSQL and I do remember having read somewhere that this won't work with certain NoSQL databases. That may also be the reason why it is not included in JHipster. But don't quote me on it.

Comment: It's not included in JHipster because the feature would need to be added to the front end as well, which means a round-trip to the server every time the validation needs to happen. See https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/2199

Comment: I am sorry for not seing this as a blocking issue. When posting to the endpoint, it would simply respond with a 4xx and the UI then informs the user about the issue (jhi-alert). This behavior is already built into jhipster when trying - for example when trying to register with an e-mail that already exists.

Answer (score 9):

When I did the above, it worked, but when I try to add a duplicate entry, I got the error: Internal Server Error on the client side. This is too generic error and I want to customize it. So I did the following:

1) Edited myapp.web.rest.errors.ErrorConstants.java and added this line to add a new error constant:

```
public static final String ERR_VALIDATION_DUPLICATE = "entity.validation.duplicate";
```

2) Edited myapp.web.rest.errors.ExceptionTranslator.java to add my error translator

```
@ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
    public ErrorVM processDataIntegrityViolationException(DataIntegrityViolationException exception) {
        return new ErrorVM(ErrorConstants.ERR_VALIDATION_DUPLICATE, exception.getMessage());
    }
```

3) Edited src/main/webapp/i18n/en/global.json and added

```
  "entity": {
...
         "validation": {
...
            "duplicate": "This value is duplicate to existing data.",
...
}
```

to match the key generated by error mapping on the server side.
You need to add the same text message but translated to all languages supported.

Notes: 
If you want to be more specific in the validation exception, You can create your own special exception that extends DataIntegrityViolationException, then catch that generic DataIntegrityViolationException in your resource class and throw your new exception. And of course map it as done in 1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a JHipster question, only JPA.

```
@Column(unique=true)
```

Please read [JPA documentation about @Column](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Column.html)